# Intersection Point between a line and a surface. Python

Tags: python, raytracing, surface

I have a set of points, and I'm trying to draw a line originating from those points. Each point has an angle value that specifies the direction that the line points towards. I want to figure out, based on the angles, if the line will intersect with a given surface, and where the point of intersection will be. My surface in question is attached below. [image: Surface]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question needs more information to get responses. Please share what approaches you have tried and if you have problems, please also share a minimum source that can give details on what you are trying to do.